# Advise needed from any ARM Cortex-M programmers out there

Tags: arm

I've decided to make the step up from using PIC to ARM Cortex-M but having trouble finding an equivalent to the PICKIT to program it.

After googling the net I have been given loads of options but have no idea what to buy.

Can anyone out there give me any advise on what to buy?

I'm so used to buying a PIC16F microcontroller, using MPLAB and the PICKIT 3 I'm unsure about what I need.

Comment: This will probably be off-topic here and an invitation to an opinion-based discussion (which is discouraged). Unless you re-phrase the question and add the relevant details. (Like - what do you need it for?)

Comment: I would recommend buying an stm32 discovery board, they're cheap, contain a target micro and can be used as a standalone st link.

Comment: Basically I'm asking this because I was researching what is the most used microcontroller in jobs as an embedded systems engineer (Mostly ARM Cortex-M). I am a PIC user but there's either no junior positions or you need 5+ years experience working with PIC.

Comment: I have now bought a CY8CKIT-059 -  Development Board, CY8C5888LTI-LP097 PSoC 5LP CPU and started using it with PSoC Creator. I do like the way you can just drag and drop components blocks onto a canvas but I'm sure this is not the most common IDE used in industry. I'm also going to try Keil uvision 5. Does anyone work with ARM Cortex-M in their jobs? If so what IDE do you use?

Comment: get one of the nucleos, the $10 or $20 are just fine.  some have uart going through the usb debugger end, some dont the NUCLEO-F031K6 for example does.  Later if you get one of the bigger ones with a debug end that can be detatched you can use as a debugger for other boards and cortex-ms from st or other brands.  you dont have to break it off either just remove a couple of jumpers.  the bbc microbit is not a bad choice, either, not as easy to program as the stm32 if doing bare metal at the register level but for what you get, you can get your feet pretty dirty...before needing something else

Answer (score 2):

I like the ST-Nucleo and the slightly more complex ST Discovery. They are inexpensive (start at around $13), versions for just about all STM32 series, built-in ST-LINK debug pod, and have Arduino style header connectors.

You can program it using free or commercial IDE/compilers, mBed compilers, and even the Arduino IDE. You can start with using the free CubeMX graphical generator to generate initialization code.

So literally all you have to spend minimally is just a $13 kit and a USB cable to get started.